# Angular & ag-grid: internal library issue with FiltersToolPanelModule

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I get troubles while trying to put a simple SideBar with AG Grid with the latest versions of angular and ag-grid as of today (9.1.3 and 23.0.2).

My simple grid conf : `sidebar = "filters"`

Dependencies to necessary enterprises modules are present.

The panel is appearing but without any column name and I get the following error in console:

```
core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: element.setAttribute is not a function
at Function.push../node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.cjs.js.Utils.addCssClass (ag-grid-community.cjs.js:1396)
```

Does anyone have an idea ? Some conflicts between dependencies ?